# Kalman Filter returns magnified estimates

Tags: python-3.x, kalman-filter

I am trying to design a multidimensional  kalman filter and I think I have the math correctly implemented. I am using the following as target trajectory:
[image]

And I have added gaussian noise of mean = [0, 0] and covariance, R = sigma**2*diag[1, 1] to generate the measurements:

[image]

But after running the filter, I get the filtered trajectory like this:
[image]

As you can see, the range suddenly shot up from [10000, -10000] to [20,000, -20000]. I tried debugging the code to see if I am missing something or have initialised anything wrongly. But I could not find the bug. Here is my code:

```
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Thu May 30 16:10:21 2019

@author: kajaree
"""
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.linalg import block_diag
from filterpy.common import Q_discrete_white_noise

sigma = 100
I = np.diag([1., 1.])
O = np.diag([0., 0.])
H = np.block([I, O, O])
R = sigma**2*I

class KalmanFilter(object):
    def __init__(self, F=None, Q=None, R=None, P0=None, x0=None):
        self.n = F.shape[1]
        self.F = F
        self.Q = np.diag([1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.])
        self.R = np.eye(self.n) if R is None else R
        self.P = np.eye(self.n) if P0 is None else P0
        self.x = np.zeros((self.n, 1)) if x0 is None else x0.T
        self.i = 0
        self.x = np.reshape(self.x, (6,1))

    def predict(self):
        self.x = np.dot(self.F, self.x)
        self.P = np.dot(self.F, np.dot(self.P, self.F.T)) + self.Q

    def update(self, z):
        v = np.subtract(np.reshape(z, (2,1)), np.dot(H, self.x))
        S = np.dot(H, np.dot(self.P, H.T)) + R
        W = np.dot(self.P, np.dot(H.T, np.linalg.inv(S))) 
        self.x = np.add(self.x, np.dot(W, v))
        #I = np.eye(self.n)
        self.P -= np.dot(W, np.dot(S, W.T)) 
        #self.P = np.dot(I - np.dot(W, H), self.P)
        '''self.P = np.dot(np.dot(I - np.dot(W, H), self.P),
                        (I - np.dot(W, H)).T) + np.dot(np.dot(W, self.R), W.T)'''



def plotter(measurements):
        plt.rcParams['legend.fontsize'] = 10
        plt.plot(measurements[:, 0], measurements[:, 1])
        plt.show()

class Measurement():
    def __init__(self, sigma=10):
        self.R = R
        self.mean = [0, 0]

    def getNoise(self):
        return np.random.multivariate_normal(self.mean, self.R)



class Sensor(object):
    def __init__(self, position, target, dt = 0.1/60, sigma=1.0):
        self.position = position
        self.measurements = None
        self.target = target
        self.sigma = sigma
        self.dt = dt
        self.R = sigma**2*I
        self.filteredMeasurement = None 
        self.covariances = None
        self.x = None
        self.P = None

    def getMeasurements(self):
        measurements = []
        measure = Measurement(self.sigma)
        for track in self.target.tracks:
            t = np.array([track[0], track[1]])
            u = measure.getNoise()
            measurement = np.add(t, u)
            measurement = np.subtract(measurement, self.position)
            measurements.append(measurement)
        self.measurements = np.array(measurements)

    def filterMeasurements(self):
        dt = self.dt
        x0 = np.block([np.array([self.measurements[0][0], self.measurements[0][1]]).T,np.array([0, 0]).T,np.array([0, 0]).T]).T
        self.target.getP()
        P0 = self.target.P0
        self.target.x0 = x0
        sigmak = (self.target.vmax/self.target.qmax)/3.0
        F = np.matrix([[1.0, 0.0, dt, 0.0, 1/2.0*dt**2, 0.0],
                        [0.0, 1.0, 0.0,  dt, 0.0, 1/2.0*dt**2 ],
                        [0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0,  dt, 0.0],
                        [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0,  dt],
                        [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0],
                        [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]])
        Q = sigmak**2*np.block([[dt**4*I/4, dt**3*I/2, dt**2*I/2],[dt**3*I/2, dt**2*I, dt*I],[dt**2*I/2, dt*I, I]])
        '''sa = 0.1
        G = np.matrix([[1/2.0*dt**2],
                       [1/2.0*dt**2],
                       [dt],
                       [dt],
                       [1.0],
                       [1.0]])
        Q = G*G.T*sigmak**2'''
        #Q = sigmak**2*np.diag([1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.])
        #q = Q_discrete_white_noise(dim = 2, dt = dt, var= 0.001)
        #Q = block_diag(q, q, q)
        #print(Q)
        kf = KalmanFilter(F, Q, self.R, P0, x0)
        self.covariances = np.zeros((len(self.measurements), F.shape[1], F.shape[1]))
        self.filteredMeasurement = np.zeros((len(self.measurements), F.shape[1], 1))
        for i, measurement in enumerate(self.measurements):
            kf.predict()
            kf.update(measurement)
            self.filteredMeasurement[i, :] = kf.x
            self.P = kf.P
            self.covariances[i, :, :] = self.P

    def plotMeasurements(self):
        plotter(self.measurements)

    def plotFilteredMeasurements(self):
        plotter(self.filteredMeasurement)


class Target(object):
    def __init__(self, vin, qin, timePeriod):
        self.x0 = np.array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]).T
        self.v0 = vin
        self.q0 = qin
        self.T = timePeriod
        self.state = None
        self.P0 = None
        self.tracks = None
        self.vmax = 0
        self.qmax = 0

    def getAngularFreq(self):
        return float(self.q0)/(2*self.v0)

    def getAmplitude(self):
        return float(self.v0**2)/self.q0

    def getMaxVelocity(self):
        vx = self.tracks[:, 2]
        vy = self.tracks[:, 3]
        v = np.sqrt(np.add(np.square(vx), np.square(vy)))
        return np.max(v)

    def getMaxAccelaration(self):
        ax = self.tracks[:, 4]
        ay = self.tracks[:, 5]
        a = np.sqrt(np.add(np.square(ax), np.square(ay)))
        return np.max(a)

    def getP(self):
        vmax = self.getMaxVelocity()
        qmax = self.getMaxVelocity()
        self.P0 = np.vstack([[ sigma**2 ,     0    ,    0    ,    0    ,    0      ,     0   ],
                             [    0     , sigma**2 ,    0    ,    0    ,    0      ,     0   ],
                             [    0     ,    0     , vmax**2 ,    0    ,    0      ,     0   ],
                             [    0     ,    0     ,    0    , vmax**2 ,    0      ,     0   ],
                             [    0     ,    0     ,    0    ,    0    ,  qmax**2  ,     0   ],
                             [    0     ,    0     ,    0    ,    0    ,    0      ,  qmax**2]])
        self.vmax = vmax
        self.qmax = qmax
    def trajectory_tracker(self):
        A = self.getAmplitude()
        w = self.getAngularFreq()
        track = []
        track.append(np.block([np.array([0, 0]).T,np.array([self.v0, self.v0]).T,np.array([self.q0, self.q0]).T]).T)
        for t in self.T:
            rx = A*np.sin(w*t)
            ry = A*np.sin(2*w*t)
            vx = self.v0 * np.cos(w*t)/2
            vy = self.v0* np.cos(2*w*t)
            ax = (-1./4)*self.q0*np.sin(w*t)
            ay = (-1)*self.q0*np.sin(2*w*t)
            x = np.block([np.array([rx, ry]).T,np.array([vx, vy]).T,np.array([ax, ay]).T]).T
            track.append(x)
        self.tracks = np.array(track)

    def plot_trajectory(self):
        plotter(self.tracks)

class FusionCenter(object):
    def __init__(self, n, target):
        self.numSensors = n
        self.sensors = []
        self.target = target
        self.P = None
        self.x = None
        self.estimates = None
        self.covariances = None

    def initiateSensors(self):
        for i in range(self.numSensors):
            position = Measurement().getNoise()
            sensor = Sensor(position, self.target)
            sensor.getMeasurements()
            self.sensors.append(sensor)
            sensor.filterMeasurements()

    def naiveFusion(self):
        self.covariances = np.zeros((len(self.sensors[0].measurements), 6, 6))
        self.estimates = np.zeros((len(self.sensors[0].measurements), 6, 1))
        for i in range(len(self.sensors[0].covariances)):
            tempP = np.zeros((6, 6))
            tempX = np.zeros((6,1))
            for j in range(len(self.sensors)):
                tempP = np.add(tempP, np.linalg.inv(self.sensors[j].covariances[i, :, :]))
                tempX = np.add(tempX, np.dot(np.linalg.inv(self.sensors[j].covariances[i, :, :]), self.sensors[j].filteredMeasurement[i, :, :]))
            self.P = np.linalg.inv(tempP)
            self.covariances[i, :, :] = np.linalg.inv(tempP)
            self.estimates[i, :, :] = np.dot(self.covariances[i, :, :], tempX)


    def trackletFusion(self):
        self.P = np.zeros((6,6))
        self.x = np.zeros((6, 1))
        self.covariances = np.zeros((len(self.sensors[0].measurements), 6, 6))
        self.estimates = np.zeros((len(self.sensors[0].measurements), 6, 1))
        for i in range(1, len(self.sensors[0].covariances)-1):
            tempP = np.zeros((6, 6))
            tempX = np.zeros((6, 1))
            for j in range(len(self.sensors)):
                Iks = np.subtract(np.linalg.inv(self.sensors[j].covariances[i, :, :]), np.linalg.inv(self.sensors[j].covariances[i-1, :, :]))
                iks = np.subtract(np.dot(np.linalg.inv(self.sensors[j].covariances[i, :, :]), self.sensors[j].filteredMeasurement[i, :]), 
                                  np.dot(np.linalg.inv(self.sensors[j].covariances[i-1, :, :]), self.sensors[j].filteredMeasurement[i-1, :]))
                #Iks = np.dot(np.dot(H.T, np.linalg.inv(R)), H)
                #iks = np.dot(np.dot(H.T, np.linalg.inv(R)), self.sensors[j].measurements[i, :, :])
                tempP = np.add(tempP, Iks)
                tempX = np.add(tempX, iks)
            pinvP = np.linalg.pinv(self.P)
            tempX += np.dot(pinvP, self.x)
            tempP = np.add(pinvP, tempP)
            self.P = np.linalg.pinv(tempP)

            self.x = np.dot(self.P, tempX)
            self.covariances[i, :, :] = self.P
            self.estimates[i, :, :] = self.x


span = np.arange(0.,1000., 0.5)
target = Target(300, 9, span)
target.trajectory_tracker()
target.plot_trajectory()
fs = FusionCenter(4, target)
fs.initiateSensors()
for i in range(4):
    fs.sensors[i].plotMeasurements()
    fs.sensors[i].plotFilteredMeasurements()
fs.naiveFusion()
plotter(fs.estimates)
fs.trackletFusion()
plotter(fs.estimates)
```

I have used piece wise white acceleration model and following for initialization:
[image: model]

[image: initial_conditions]

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It looks like the F matrix is not really correct. I would say the last raw should be `[O, O, I]` instead of `[O, I, I]`

Comment: Thank you. I have tried that. And the range is now as desired. But I am still not getting the correct result. I have updated the question.

Comment: Nice, I'll try to find out what's wrong.

Comment: Thanks. I added the latest version my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in the definition of the time step.

You initialized the Target object with the time defined by `span`:

```
span = np.arange(0.,1000., 0.5)
target = Target(300, 9, span)
```

That means your `dt = 0.5`.

When calling the filter you used the `dt` from your other initialization:

```
def filterMeasurements(self):
    dt = self.dt
```

where `dt = 0.0016666`:

```
class Sensor(object):
    def __init__(self, position, target, dt = 0.1/60, sigma=1.0):
```

This mismatch corrupted the velocity and acceleration and hence the trajectory.

The filtered trajectory looks nice now:

[image: Filtered Trajectory]